# Using ScriptNotify with HTTP URIs

Tags: c#, windows, webview, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when calling window.external.notify.

According to MSDN, AllowedScriptNotifyUris, AnyScriptNotifyUri, and AllowedScriptNotifyUrisProperty are not supported in apps compiled for Windows 8.1.

The URIs must use HTTPS but unfortunately, our web pages are still under development and use HTTP.

On Windows 8.1, is there a way to add URIs using HTTP in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest or any other way to use ScriptNotify with HTTP ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered on the same problem and unfortunately, there is no way to use HTTP protocol. However; I created a self-signed certificate and hosted my local web server. And, I installed the self signed certificate to the Windows Phone.

I used this guide for the creating certificate: http://pankajmalhotra.com/Simple-HTTPS-Server-In-Python-Using-Self-Signed-Certs/

Also to be able to install the certificate on the phone, you need to convert it to cer. http://www.networksolutions.com/support/what-is-the-difference-between-a-crt-and-a-cer-file/